# Which way should I create a list of objects when sending POST request

Tags: rest, http-post, django-rest-framework

When I creating same type objects and save them into database, should I send a list of that objects in one request or should I send individually for each one?

For example, I would like to create a todo list, I can create multiple todos, then click save to send a list of todos, or when I finish editing one todo, I save it directly.

The first way can save request numbers, only one request needed to create many objects. But is the first way RESTful? All infomation about create in REST is creating a single object, but will there be poblems if increasing requests numbers?

----Edit

Thank you guys answering me.

For a more spicific usecase, I am using Django Rest Framework. I created a Todo model and a corresponding serializer. I am wondering, how could I create a list of Todos? I tried to send a list of Todos to serializer, and expecting serializer can automatically loop through it as same as getting a list of instance. But that doesn't work. I know I may be able to create a loop to call create method everytime. But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: That may depend upon your web interface.  You have a limit about the size of a http request (about 4kO).  Expending the number of item on server size, it's just a loop added.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in REST that tells you what kind of payload you are allowed to use. You can POST/PUT whatever you want - one entity representation or many representations, in lists, dictionaries, XML, URL-encoded key/values or JSON, what ever suits your use case best.

In your case you might even want to send a delta/diff list of changes on the client: Lets for instance say your client loads some existing 3 todo items. Then the user modifies one of them, deletes another one and adds a new one. You can either do that in three requests or one single request with add/modify/delete operations encoded in it. Both ways are valid and the best solution depends on your use case and constraints like bandwidth, processing power and network round-trip time.

Comment: Thanks your anwser. In your example, I think, using three requests with different HTTP methods(CRUD) is more appropriate. I was doing things as you said before, I was only using POST to do create,update,deted with a "action" in the post body. But that way is pretty old style, isn't it?

Comment: > "But that way is pretty old style" ... why is that? Choose what works best for your scenario. If latency and bandwidth is not an issue then your solution is fine. But batch-operations is not prohibited by REST.